# If $\sum a_n^p$ converges, then $\sum a_n^q$ also converges? for $1 \leq p \leq q$ and $a_n > 0$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was able to give a counterexample to the reciprocal, but I'm having trouble proving this one (I even tried to look for a counterexample, but I couldn't). Any suggestions on how to do it, or any counterexample?

Comment: If $\sum a_n^p$ converges, since $a_n > 0$, there is $N$ such that $n \geq N \implies a_n < 1$. Since $q \geq p$, $\lvert a_n^q \rvert \leq a_n^p$. You can use this.

Comment: I had trouble seeing that when $ a_n^\gamma < 1 $, the higher $\gamma$ the smaller the sum (lack of attention). Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $a_n^p$->0 so $a_n$->0 and you can find a $n_o \in \mathbb N$ that $a_n<1$ for every $n>=n_o$. So for $n>=n_o:0<a_n^q$<$a_n^p$ and your $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty a_n^q$ converges.

Comment: But this doesn't hold just for those value of $n \leq n_o$? And the other values?

Comment: I thought this was obvious and didn't write it with details.You want to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^q$ converges but notice that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^q$=$\sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1} a_n^q$ + $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty a_n^q$ and when you sum $n_0-1$ things in $\mathbb R$($a_n$ are all real numbers for all n) then the sum is always a real number.

Comment: Ah! It makes more sense now. You have a sum that goes up to a certain value $n_o - 1$ (which is a real number) and another sum that has been verified (the case of $n_o$ to $\infty$) that converges to another value. These two sums together hold all $n$.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the question i did below?

Comment: The sum in the left part($n=1$ till $ n_0-1$) is not $n_0-1$ its just a real number.Imagine summing anything in $\mathbb R$. Since $a_n$ converges we can tell that its a bounded sequence so you can find an M>0 that this sum is bounded by $M^q$*($no-1$) but thats not the case.The case is that if you have to see if a series converges or not you dont have necessarily see what the series looks like from the start but after an $n_o$

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that. Once again you helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If the original sum converges, then we must have that $\lim a_n^p=0$, which implies that $\lim a_n=0$. Wlog we can assume that $a_n<1$ as well, which implies that $a_n^q<a_n^p$, so the given series also converges.

Comment: this $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ implies that $\sum a_n$ converges also? Because the case where $a_n = 1/n$ is a problem, right?

Comment: $\lim a_n=0$ does not say us is general case that the series $\sum a_n$ converges as the example you said.We use it to make $a_n^q$ smaller than $a_n^p$(since $a_n$<1 for $n>=n_0$).

Comment: @Fredgrub No, only the other way is true (i.e. $\sum a_n$ converges $\implies$ $a_n \to 0$).

Answer (score 1):

As, $1\le p\le q \implies |a_n|^p < |a_n|^q $,
By comparison test $\sum a_{n}^{q} $ converge , as $\sum a_{n}^{p} $ converge.